# if we made three strings in java through string literal String A = "hel"+"lo"; String B = "lo"; String C = "hel"+B; . A == C be true but showing false

Tags: java

if we made three strings in java through string literal String A = "hel"+"lo"; String B = "lo"; String C = "hel"+B; . A == C be true but output is false.. as both will share same memory in stringpool. i am bit confused why this is happening.

Code that prints false:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String A = "hel" + "lo";
        String B = "lo";
        String C = "hel" + B;
        System.out.println(A == C);
    }
}
```

Code that prints true:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String A = "hel" + "lo";
        String B = "lo";
        String C = "hel" + "lo";
        System.out.println(A == C);
    }
}
```

Why do I get different results as both are the same?

Comment: `A` `B` and `C` are three different object.

Comment: Why would you expect `A` and `C` to share the same `String` object?

Comment: beacuse string created by literal having same content share memory in stringpool

Comment: I think this question is **not** about how to compare strings in Java. I think the question is related to how exactly the string pool works when two string literals are appended.

Comment: `String C = "hel" + B;` is not a string constant because the string variable `B` is not `final` and therefore doesn't count as string constant. Only if you write `final String B = "lo";` is `B` a string constant and only then is `String C = "hel" + B;` a constant string expression that the compiler evaluates.

Comment: See [JLS § 4.3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.3).

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this example

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String A = "hel" + "lo";
        String B = "lo";
        String C = "hel" + B;
        System.out.println(A == C);
    }
}
```

is that the variable `B` is mutable and therefore the expression `"hel" + B` is not a constant expression.

The compiler translates the line `String C = "hel" + B;` into something similar to

```
        String C = "hel".concat(B);
```

which results in a new string object that is different from the string literal `"hello"`.

---

If you turn `B` into a [constant variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) and write

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String A = "hel" + "lo";
        final String B = "lo";
        String C = "hel" + B;
        System.out.println(A == C);
    }
}
```

then the expression `"hel" + B` is a [constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29) and the compiler can compute the value of this expression.

Answer (score -1):

The Java String class equals() method compares the two given strings based on the content of the string. The == operator compares references not values. Try to understand the below program, you will know the difference.

```
 String A = "hel" + "lo";
 String B = "lo";
 String C = "hel" + B;
 System.out.println(A.equals(C)); //true 

class Teststringcomparison{  
 public static void main(String args[]){  
   String s1="Sachin";  
   String s2="Sachin";  
   String s3=new String("Sachin");  
   System.out.println(s1==s2);//true (because both refer to same instance)  
   System.out.println(s1==s3);//false(because s3 refers to instance created in nonpool)  
 }  
}
```

Comment: OP is particularly interested in why `C` does not get the same string pool value as `A`.

Comment: Because == operator compares references(memory address) not values, java use string equlas to do the string comparison.

Comment: You are still missing the point, two string variables can still be `==` if they refer to the same string pool entry - OP is wondering why C and A do not behave like that. OP does not want to know that `equals` should be used but why `==` does not work in his case.

Comment: ya i m not asking about equals method i am interested in string pool. luk20302 sir can you please tell me how internally this statement String C = "hel" + B is working so that it is not getting same memory refrence

Comment: yes, i think it is the OP problem.